# How to control overlap image color?

Tags: matlab, colors, overlap

I overlapped two images A and B; The overlap image show green-magenta colors: I want blue and red. I used the following code:

```
  c=imfuse(A,B,'falsecolor','Scaling','joint');
  redChannel = c(:, :, 1);
  blueChannel = c(:, :, 3);
  rgbImage = cat(2,redChannel,blueChannel);
  imshow (rgbImage)
```

Comment: Can you build your own RGB image without using any function? For instance: `rgbImage(:,:,1) = A; rgbImage(:,:,2) = 0; rgbImage(:,:,3) = B;`

Answer (score 0):

By default `imfuse` uses the value `'green-magenta'` for the option `'ColorChannels'`. You can use `'red-cyan'` instead:

```
c = imfuse(A, B, 'falsecolor', 'Scaling', 'joint', 'ColorChannels', 'red-cyan');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

Comment: Can you suggest a function with better color control?

Comment: Sure, but I have to admit I have a hard time understanding your question. Can you be more specific on what you want to achieve, and e.g. provide images of the input images and expected outcome? That would help a lot in writing a relevant answer.